# SQL cannot search

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In my SQL table `Image`, when i perform a search query

```
SELECT * FROM Image WHERE platename LIKE 'WDD 666'
```

it return no result(using other column to search then no problem).

The all the column data was inserted by C# code. (If enter data manually search works.)
  [image: SQL]
now i suspect that the words `WDD 666` wasn't english alphabet. is this possible?

In c#,
the plate number was generate by using tesseract wrapper `string type`.

what should i do to search the plate number?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What is the trim() and len() of platename, i.e.   SELECT '*'+plateName+'*',len(plateName).    You may have extra non-printable characters in the field...

Comment: It is possible that you have different collation set up than what your query is using.  Check this question out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531453/sql-server-2008-difference-between-collation-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your case matches, I'm going to rule out Case-sensitivity.

There may be leading or trailing blank spaces - Try this..

`SELECT * FROM Image WHERE platename LIKE '%WDD 666%'`

Comment: Thanks it works, btw just now i did try 
SELECT * FROM Image WHERE platename LIKE 'WDD%'
but cant..

Comment: Your column is VarChar - so there won't be trailing spaces, but there very well could be leading blank spaces. Try with a leading `%` sign.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this command:

```
SELECT '*'+plateName+'*',len(plateName)
FROM image.
```

I suspect platename has some non-printable characters in the field.

It appears to be a CR/LF at the end of the data.   You can use

```
UPDATE image SET plateName = replace(plateName,char(13)+char(10),'') 
WHERE plateName like '%'+char(13)+char(10)+'%'
```

If you get a positive row count, you'll know there was CR/LF data and it was removed.   If you run the select afterwards, your lengths should be 7 and 8 based on your sample data

Comment: That indicates you've get extra, not printable characters in the field.  While the wildcard answer above will work to get the records, make sure the code that uses the retrieved data properly deals with the non-printable characters...

Comment: As Raj pointed out, Varchar() data will prevent trailing data (spaces), so I suspect you've got a carriage return, linefeed at the end of the data.

Comment: That's what this site is all about...   Have a great day